# CGBitmapContextCreate bitsPerComponent for RBG565

Tags: objective-c, cgbitmapcontextcreate, cgcontextref

I'm trying to create a `CGContextRef` using `CGBitmapContextCreate`. The bitmap I want to create is RBG565 (red and blue are 5 bits, green is 6 bits). One of the parameters for `CGBitmapContextCreate` is `bitsPerComponent`. Since I have variable `bitsPerComponent`, I'm not sure if I just set it as 5, or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreGraphics doesn't support RGB565 natively. You'll need to create your bitmap context with a different format and then convert to RGB565 using something like `vImageConvert_ARGB8888toRGB565`.

Comment: Thanks, let me give this a try later.